# Can I use language other than English for default resources?

Tags: android, localization, non-english

Android supports multiple application resource locales. Default strings are in `values` directory, other languages use `values-XX` directories. Can I set up Android Studio project to treat `strings.xml` in `values` directory (without language specification) as non-English strings (e. g. German)? I am 100% sure that all users know German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android makes no assumption about what language the strings are in `res/values/`. It is simply the default set of strings to use, for cases where you do not provide translations for some specific language.

If you want to use German strings in `res/values/`, you are welcome to do so. In that case, your English translations would go into `res/values-en/` or a similar directory, should you someday elect to provide such translations.

Comment: Thanks. Can I set up Android Studio to use German spell-checking for these strings?

Comment: @jiwopene: Android Studio's spelling hints are not strictly for string resources. My guess is that they are controlled by the dictionaries in Editor > Spelling in Studio's Settings dialog. You might be able to find `.dic` files that you could add there for German, but note that those hints would affect anything where spelling is checked, not just string resources.

Comment: "Android makes no assumption about what language the strings are in `res/values/`" This is not completely true, you will run into problems with multiple languages if you don't provide English at `res/values/`. For example:  when an app is shipped with these strings: [`values/strings.xml` (German), `values-fr/strings.xml` (French)] and the user has device locales: [en-UK, fr-FR] in that order, then the strings used are `values/strings.xml` (German), where you might expect fr-FR. I tested this on many Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use German by default. Just put German strings in strings.xml, and for support of other languages ​​use values-XX